# (SQL) Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, sorting, datetime, arraylist

I have problem with this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Full error: https://pastebin.com/Ex2x1tuS

I tried to google it and I found something but still It don't work.
I want to add from sql to arraylist and then sort that datetime from sql.
Now my code is:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM db";
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next()) {
    String vp = rs.getString("Vardas,Pavard\u0117");
    String i = rs.getString("\u012Emon\u0117");
    String pd = rs.getString("Patik. Data");
    String id = rs.getString("Iki Data");

    List<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>(); 
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String realid = "";
    realid = dateFormatter.format(id);
    try {
        list.add((Date) dateFormatter.parse(realid));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.err.print(ex);
    }
}
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Which `Date` are you `import`ing?

Comment: I am importing dates from sql example:08/22/2017 , 04/23/2017

Comment: Right, let's try this again: Fill in the blank based on your current code: `import java.___.Date`.

Comment: `import java.text.DateFormat; `, `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`,` import java.util.Date;`

Comment: The `format` method takes a `Date` and you're passing a `String`

Comment: How to fix it? How to add dates to variable from sql

Comment: The `ResultSet` class has `getDate()` methods that return a `java.sql.Date`, if that's what you want to do.